# If the main challenges limiting quantum computing's abilities will be passed, will even video games be run on quantum computers?

Tags: architecture

I'm terribly sorry for my lack of knowledge in (quantum) computer architecture, I still need to learn a lot. But I'd like to know whether quantum computers can execute the same tasks (like running a GUI) as regular computers if backed with the right hardware, or are they solely for computing difficult tasks.

Comment: Quantum computers can perform any computation that a classical computer can just as (asymptotically) efficiently. However there are 2 things that need to be taken into account: (1) as you said it needs to be backed with the right hardware. This is not only more advanced things like GUIs but even basic things like memory still need to be engineered. And (2) even if you had all the components, it still may be faster to run your video game on a classical computer if no particularly "hard" (complexity-wise) tasks are required to run the game.